# Clone a markdown table column in browser

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I have a `.md` file with a single columned table.
That file has about 50 rows but here is a pattern example with just 5 rows.
I want to clone the column so to have two adjacent columns with the same basic structure.

**Current input:**

```
| First name |
|------------|
|   Name 1   |
|   Name 2   |
|   Name 3   |
|   Name 4   |
|   Name 5   |
```

**Desired input by cloning:**

```
| First name | First name |
|------------|------------|
|   Name 1   |   Name 1   |
|   Name 2   |   Name 2   |
|   Name 3   |   Name 3   |
|   Name 4   |   Name 4   |
|   Name 5   |   Name 5   |
```

I desire to do the cloning in edit mode (edit page), so to save the cloned data in an edit.

If I copy-paste the column → the clone will appear under the first table, but not right of it so another operation is needed.
I think JavaScript `cloneNode()` method is useful and I tried the following code to clone the first example ("current input") while in edit page:

```
document.querySelector("#wmd-preview > pre:nth-child(3) > code").cloneNode();
```

But the code wasn't cloned and JavaScript console outputted `<code></code>` only.

**How will you clone the table while in edit page?**

Answer (score 0):

CloneNode function doesn't do deep cloning unless mentioned. Try this,

```
document.querySelector("#wmd-preview > pre:nth-child(3) > code").cloneNode(true);
```

Ref: [Duplicating an element (and its style) with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848445/duplicating-an-element-and-its-style-with-javascript) &
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp